# Web service maven build jar does not work

Tags: eclipse, web-services, maven, jar, pom.xml

I would like to build a web service project in jar which can be deployed on a JBoss server. This can be done if I compile a `.war` project, which makes 12Mo with this content
[image: content of my .war web service]

but in my pom.xml when I want to specify that I would like a .jar project I get an archive which makes 10Ko and which contains almost nothing like this picture

[image: content of my .jar web service]

Here's my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MonWebServiceFacility</groupId>
<artifactId>MonWebServiceFacility</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<!--<packaging>war</packaging>-->
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <cxf.version>3.1.7</cxf.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    ...SOME DEPENENCIES...
</dependencies>
```

So how can I build jar archive to be deployed in my JBoss server ?

Here's my project architecture :

[image: project architecture]

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `<packaging>jar</packaging>` in pom.xml and also need to create web.xml into webaap>WEB_INF folder.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```